# Android SDK installation from other system installed files

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Can i install the android studio SDK files from another system where SDK is already installed.

I have installed android studio in one system with fully installed SDK files, and I would like to install same SDK in my system. Is it possible?

Comment: just copy SDK from intalled system and paste that on your system on your SDK location and then open android studio SDK Location example path in windows: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

Just copy `SDK` from intalled system and paste that on your system on your `SDK location` and then open `Android Studio SDK Location`.Path example in `windows: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

**it is possible**

Just copy android SDK from installed system and paste that on another system and locate it in android studio

[image]